# Error in DataTable when Apply rails pagination

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatable, pagination

I am using DataTable in Rails application.

DataTable Partial

---

```
<% if @messages.present? and @messages.length > 0 %>
  <h4><%= t('labels.message')%></h4>
  <table id="messages_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ></th>
        <th class="hide"></th>
        <th class="hide"></th>
        <th><strong><%= t('labels.date')%> </strong></th>
        <th><strong><%= t('labels.sender')%> </strong></th>
        <th><strong><%= t('labels.subject')%> </strong></th>
        <th><strong><%= t('labels.action')%></strong></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="center" style="min-width:20px;"><img src="/assets/details_open.png" rel="<%= message.id %>"></td>
        <td class="hide"><%= message.body.html_safe %></td>
        <td style="display:none"><%= message.created_at.to_i %></td>
        <td><%= parse_datetime(message.created_at.to_s, :dtconcise) %>           </td>
        <td><%= message.sender %></td>
        <td><%= message.subject %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to("Delete", delete_message_path(message) ,:class => "table2",
              :confirm => t('confirmation.delete_message')) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------


  On First load when I click on  image on first 'td' of any 'tr' of this table(each first 'td' have a image)  then second 'td' data of this 'tr' will be display in a separate row below of this 'tr', by-default second 'td' will be hide means second 'td' data will be hide/show on that 'td' image click. 
 And the main Problem is here when I apply pagination with ajax  and then render the table partial then hide/show of data on click on first 'td' of any 'tr' does not work. for this I  have reinitialize dataTable again.

  I have written code like after pagination to render the result on particular DIV in the 'get_message.js.erb' file.

```
$('#message_list').html('<tr><td colspan="5"><h5 style="text-align:   center; margin-top: 100px;"><%= t('messages.no_result_found') %></h5></td></tr>');

$('#paginator_message').html('');
```

```
$('#message_list').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial =>"messages_list", :format => [:html]) %>');

$('#paginator_message').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@messages, :params => {:controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'get_messages'}, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

```
oTable = $('#message_list').find("#messages_table").dataTable({
  aoColumnDefs: [
    {
      bSortable: false,
      aTargets: [0, 6]
    }
  ],
  aaSorting: [[3, "desc"]],
  "aoColumns": [
    {
      "iDataSort": null
    }, {
      "iDataSort": null
    }, {
      "iDataSort": 2
    }, {
      "iDataSort": 2
    }, {
      "iDataSort": 4
    }, {
      "iDataSort": 5
    }, {
      "iDataSort": null
    }
  ],
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bRetrieve" : true,
  "bProcessing" : true
});

oTable.fnDraw();
messageLoad(oTable);
```

after pagination when we click on first td of DataTable then it gives error like:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aoData' of null"

Comment: why aren't you using the plugin pagination?

Comment: because there are to much of data like thousands of records and DataTable   wants all the records on load time so I did use rails pagination to reduce the overhead of loading time.

Comment: So you reload page each time? Why not use the ajax serverside methods built into plugin then?

Comment: Why not use Stream Table, it retrevies a chunk of data after a certain interval untill all the data is loaded thereby speeding up the loadtime of the views, here is the link for it https://github.com/jiren/StreamTable.js and demo   http://jiren.github.io/StreamTable.js/stream.html

Comment: Try this http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Use server side datatable

Comment: RSB,
What do you mean by server side dataTable, could you please give me details about that.